# How much of your HTML should be in an angular controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it bad practice to have large paragraphs stored in your controllers?

For example you want to output several large paragraphs in an ng-repeat, and as a result you make this data structure in your controller:

```
$scope.paragraphs['300 word paragraph','400 word paragraph','200 word paragraph']
```

for

```
<p ng-repeat="paragraph in paragraphs">{{paragraph}}</p>
```

Basically at what point do you stop abstracting your HTML to your javascript?

Comment: What is the context for this question? Seems rather abstract as it is now which makes it opinion based and therefore off-topic

Comment: To answer your question, none, you shouldnt have any HTML in your controller. If you have a big list of data that you want to populate into your view, you could use a factory to provide you with that data. Having variables with strings in it is fine, but once those start to get to large you could move them to a factory to clean it up.

Comment: *"at what point do you stop abstracting your HTML to your javascript"* **Immediately** If the html isn't data-driven (isn't coming from a database or webservice) it should be in a template.

Comment: @KevinB so to clarify ng-repeat should never be used as a way of writing less html, and should only be used in data-driven applications?

Comment: I mean, sure, use it to write less html, but, that's not what you are using it for. You just moved the html from the template to the controller. There isn't any less html.

Comment: Okay thank you. You've elucidated the role of ng-repeat for me. One last question I have is: Is there any merit to asynchronously fetching the static content of a website from a database instead of just putting it in the HTML?

Comment: No, unless it isn't needed by a significant percentage of users and omitting it will significantly affect the pagesize.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making an angular application in the absence of anything data driven so I was using ng-repeats to write less code.

The answer is that my HTML shouldn't be in there at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the text and the data, then you should abstract the text following the numbers out so that it could be dealt differently ie translation or whatever. In bigger apps the data would be coming through ajax so you would want to minimize the data.